# Angular JS - Populating an array of objects with data from another

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object

I am working on a project which allows users to filter jobs based on criteria such as city, job level and job category. As the user clicks on a filter the search results will be filtered, but so too will the filters themselves.

To do this I plan to get my list of filter cities, levels and categories from the filtered job objects. **My question is how, in Angular, can I create 3 object arrays using data from a 4th object array?**

My Jobs array ($scope.programs) has the following format:

```
[
    {
        title: "HR Analyst",
        city: "Jacksonville",
        state: "Florida",
        country: "United States",
        region: "North America",
        level: "Full Time Analyst",
        category: " Human Resources"
    }
]
```

and I then plan to create 3 object arrays which store the name of the filter and its availability. So $scope.cities might look like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "London",
        available: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "Sydney",
        available: "false",
    },
]
```

Comment: Are you asking someone to write you a function that will take one object array as an input and return 3 new arrays as output? You state that your question is whether or not it's possible to "create 3 object arrays using data from a 4th object array." Why would you think this wouldn't be possible? What have you tried so far to achieve your desired effect? Why did it not work?

Comment: Is frontend best place to do those calculations?

Comment: Hi Dan, I do think its possible. I'm just not sure how to go about it, hence me asking for help! I know that I will need to use a forEach loop to loop through the items in scope.programs but Im not sure how to create the other object arrays and assign program.city from the programs array (for instance) to city.name in the cities array.

Comment: Okay, so then what about the set of questions that appears at the end of my comment. What have you tried so far to achieve your desired effect? Why did it not work? It sounds like you might want to [read up on working with arrays and objects in Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter4.html).

Comment: Hi  Krzysztof, I planned on doing it in the front end as I'm going to filter the programs data within the controller and then update these further arrays based on the results of the filters.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with [Angular filters](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp)? You shouldn't need to construct multiple arrays that filter the same dataset. Just create multiple Angular filters to provide a filtered view of the data you want to surface.

Comment: Hi Dan, yes I've created custom angular filters to filter the jobs themselves. But the options by which the user can filter by should change as they perform searches. I think its called a multi-faceted search. So someone searches for jobs in London and this returns a set of jobs. None of the jobs returned are for the category Human Resources (for example) so the Human Resources filter should not show. This is why I'm creating the arrays. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure, that makes sense, but you shouldn't need to create a new array to filter out the undesirable values. That's precisely what Angular filters are for.

Comment: Ok maybe I'll read up on that then. Forgive me, this is my first Angular project so I'm still not familiar with the "Angular way" of doing things yet.

Comment: No need to apologize to me - believe me when I say I've asked my fair share of Angular n00b questions. I probably did yesterday, in fact! Angular has incredible depth and power...there are very few experts out there.

Comment: [This JSFiddle looks like it demonstrates some pretty sophisticated use of Angular filters](http://jsfiddle.net/LifeOnLars/HWa2m/24/). It's probably not _exactly_ what you're looking for, but maybe close?

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty close but probably too much syntax that as a n00b I wouldn't want to replicate without understanding tbh. I'd rather add code that I understand and might not be the best solution and then go back and re-factor as I get more experienced.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to populate my arrays with:

```
$scope.getFilters = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.programs, function(program) {
        $scope.filterCities.push({
            name: program.city,
            available: true
        });
        $scope.filterCategories.push({
            name: program.category,
            available: true
        });
        $scope.filterLevels.push({
            name: program.level,
            available: true
        });
    });

    console.log($scope.filterCities);
    console.log($scope.filterCategories);
    console.log($scope.filterLevels);

};
```

Although after speaking with Dan Forbes I believe I should restrict my Cities, Categories and Levels using custom Angular filters rather than creating arrays. I hope this helps someone.